# Como puedo hcaer que el id de un select sea dinamico?

Tags: javascript, select

Genero una tabla por cada elemento de una lista.

cada tabla generada tiene un para de Select's los cuales tienen un ID estatico  id="selectorCategory" id"slctSubcategoria", etc. estoy ids los uso para popular el select con el metodo onchange

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Concepts/GetCategory",
        data: { categoria: val },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            var markup = "<option value='0'>---Selecciona una subcategoria---</option>";
            for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                markup += "<option value=" + result[x].value + ">" + result[x].text + "</option>";
            }
            $("#slctSubcategoria").html(markup).show();

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
```

el problema es que los ids de mis select son estaticos, como los puedo hacer tipo dinámicos para funcione sin importar en que elemento de mi intereracción lo este usando

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AllConceptos" id="selectorCategory" onchange="GetCategory(this.value)">
    <option>---Selecciona una categoria---</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.Subcategoria" id="slctSubcategoria" onchange="GetConcepts(this.value)">
<option>---Selecciona una subcategoria---</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" id="slctConcept" onchange="GetDataConcept(this.value)">
<option>---Selecciona un concepto---</option></select>
```

Comment: Oscar podrias ser mas claro en tu pregunta, no logro comprender que es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias @demepty, no hice la pregunta correcta, lo que necesitaba era solo hacer los id de un Select dimanico, pero ya lo resolvi. en mi cshtml le agregue un identificador al id de esta forma:  id="slctSubcategoria@(item.Id)"  onchange="GetConcepts(this.value, @item.Id)" y en el onchange le agregue como segundo parametro el id que necesitaba para diferenciar mi seletc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

de esta forma solucione mi problema, e hice que el id de mi select sea dinamico.

a mi cshtml le agregare in identificador id="selectorCategory@(item.Id)" y se lo envie a mi funcion del onchange como un segundo parámetro para poder concatenare ese valor al momento de popular el select que queria

```
<select class="form-control" asp-items="@Model.AllConceptos" id="slctSubcategoria@(item.Id)" onchange="GetCategory(this.value, @item.Id)">
<option>---Selecciona una categoria---</option>
```

```
function GetCategory(val, val2) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Concepts/GetCategory",
            data: { categoria: val },
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (result) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>---Selecciona una subcategoria---</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + result[x].value + ">" + result[x].text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#slctSubcategoria" + val2).html(markup).show();

            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
    };
```